# d3 tree join to single child

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Is there any simple way to remove duplicate children in the d3 tree visualization.

Given the data:

```
{
        name: "certificates",
        id: "cert-root",
        children: [
            {
                name: "ISO",
                id: "cert-iso",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "co-01",
                        name: "CO-01"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "co-02",
                        name: "CO-02"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "HIPPA",
                id: "cert-hippa",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "co-01",
                        name: "CO-01"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "co-o2",
                        name: "CO-02"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

I would like to make the parents, as in this example `cert-iso` and `cert-hippa` point to a single instance of the children as they have duplicated id. I know that you can cast your own nodes, but is there any built in way to do it?

Example of implementation on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cahexuhoxu/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need, I've solved it with some lodash magic :)

```
var nodes = tree.nodes(data);

nodes = _.uniq(nodes, 'id');

var links = tree.links(nodes);

_.each(links, function (o, i) {
    links[i].target = _.find(nodes, {id: o.target.id});
});
```